# Spring Quatrz Dynamic Annotation Based Java Config

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

Sorry i had to ask it over here as i searched a lot tried many things but failed to achieve the result.

So what i am trying to do is i have a service which give me the list of the Jobs along with the interval at which they need to run so , what i want to do is loop over the list of the jobs and schedule them using Spring Quartz and i want to do them using the java config and not XML based .

This application will be a web application which will be running on a server, a maven project.

I found result and the are mainly using the Custom Annotation . Is there any sample or example which i can try or use.?

The problem is we are very new to all this and none of us have a idea how to proceed with this so any help is very appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Vishesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your @Confugation class implement SchedulingConfigurer. This allows you to schedule tasks programmatically. For example

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableScheduling
    public class TaskConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer{

        @Autowired
        private TaskDao taskDao; // implement TaskDao to read tasks from DB

       @Override
       public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar){
           List<Task> tasks = taskDao.findAllTasks();
           for(Task task : tasks){
               Runnable taskJob = createTaskJob(task); // create task by reflection
              taskRegistrar.addCronTask(taskJob , task.getCronExpression());
           }
       }
    }

    public class Task implements Serializable{

         private String cronExpression;
         private String jobClass;

         //getters and setters
    }
```

Comment: Hi ekem thanks for reply . do you have a sample for doing java config for spring and annotation? Actually we are using for 1st time and dont have much experince. I was using this link to implement https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/10/spring-quartz-integration-with-custom.html

Answer (score 0):

@ekem chitsiga workaround will also do. Following is another alternate to run your cron jobs based on the cron epressions you set.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class Scheduler {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(Scheduler.class);

@Autowired
private JobRepository jobRepository;

/*
 * Cron expression ="0 0/1 * 1/1 * ?" for every minute
 */
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ?")
public void sendNotification() {
    logger.info("Initializing Cron job scheduler....");
    //Do you scheduler specific work here
}

}
```

Comment: Hi Abdullah thanks for reply . do you have a sample for doing java config for spring and annotation? Actually we are using for 1st time and dont have much experince. I was using this link to implement https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/10/spring-quartz-integration-with-custom.html

Comment: this can be used in a spring project. Just copy this class in your project and change your cron expression accoring to your need.

Comment: Abdullah i am sorry but do you have a sample how to use this ? As i am new to this i am not able to figure out.

Comment: The code i posted is what i am using in my spring project for scheduling simple cron jobs. Just copy this code and paste it in a newly created class 'Scheduler'. Deploy your project on your server. And you will see your sendNotification method being called every minute.